# Compression by comprehension using machine learning techniques

Tags: machine-learning, compression, data-science

I'm an aspiring data scientist (presently just a software developer) and I've just got this (foolish?) idea.

So far (as far as I know), we’ve being using compression algorithms based on replacing the standard way of encoding data by a smarter one. What if we could compress data by comprehension? For example by generating a kind of abstract from which we can recover the original data.

Just think of how our minds work. By associating ideas one with another.

Can machine learning techniques learn and understand the data (and how it is represented on disk) so that it can be generated back from an abstract being generated by the algorithm?

Comment: Yes, there are such approaches and methods (mostly for images, as this is a medium with easy to find patterns), they are far away from being usable compression methods in the JPEG sense, but they show that in principle it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but then you would have to transfer a representation of the associations and "comprehension" to the other end in order to decompress. That representation will likely be much larger than the data you were trying to compress.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually similar ideas that are, at least to a some degree, already realized.

For instance [Autoencoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) allows for the compression (encoder part) and re-construction of original data (decoder part).

This technique coupled with the idea of [Thought Vector](https://www.quora.com/What-are-thought-vectors) which, sort of, "encodes" concept/meaning/comprehension in a single vector would result into something you have described.